# Rails activerecord sorting by two tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I was just wondering if it was possible to join a table and then sort by a column on both.

For instance if I have two tables, one called lollipops and the other featured_lollipops:

lollipops can belong_to featured_lollipops

Both tables have a column called "sweetness"

Is it possible to make a query like:

```
Lollipop.joins(:featured_lollipops).order("sweetness ASC")
```

Where the returned result being an ActiveRecord hash of all lollipops sorted by sweetness even if the sweetness comes from the joined table?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I need to be able to sort by the sweetness combined, not the sweetness on each column.

Answer (score 0):

In the `order` method you can have a `lollipops.sweetness` and `featured_lollipops.sweetness`, to distinguish between the 2 tables.
Here's an example:

```
.order("lollipops.sweetness ASC, featured_lollipops.sweetness DESC")
```

Comment: I've tried doing that but that just seems to prioritize the lollipops table.

ie it will look like this:

Lollipop - Sweetness 1
Lollipop - Sweetness 2
Lollipop - Sweetness 1 (Featured)

Comment: Well, this is just an example of how to use the table names in the sort method. You have to adjust it to your needs of sorting.

Comment: Why would one be ASC and the other DESC?

Comment: My question is more how to combine and sort by both at the same time, not separately. Thanks for the response regardless :)

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
a = Lollipop.joins(:featured_lollipop) + FeaturedLollipop.all
a.sort_by {|f| f.sweetness}
```

Comment: I'd only like to pull back in the FeaturedLollipop records that belong_to the Lollipop records. i.e. the records associated through the featured_lollipop_id column.

Comment: Revised. Is the original post correct? does lollipop belong_to featured_lollipop? Or the other way round?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe you can do this.

```
Lollipop.joins(:featured_lollipop).
  select(
    "(lollipop.sweetness + featured_lollipop.sweetness) AS sorting_sweetness, lollipop.*"
  ).order("sorting_sweetness DESC")
```